# using sdl in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios4, sdl

I am thinking of using SDL in an iPhone app. Can it be done without any major problems on an app which uses iOS 4.2 or iOS 4.3 SDKs?

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, the SDL framework for iPhone isn't mature yet. But I've never tried to use it on iPhone because I found a better 2D engine, before try SDL, which is [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/).
Is you're planning to port an old project on iPhone, I only can tell you to try...

But if you're planning to work on a new project with SDL because you're more familiar with SDL than others engine. I think you should go on Cocos2D.
Anyway it's my point of view, hope this help you to choose what is best.
Regards, kl94